# Can I get a proper tiling window manager in KDE

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, window-managers, tiling

I've been a bit conflicted about switching over to a tiling window manager. I made the switch a while ago and I really like it for some things but for other things I don't. So I ended up switching back to my trusty KDE.

However, when switching between my virtual desktops I can't help but think how awesome it would be if I could have a proper tiling window manager in KDE. I know that kwin has some tiling options but IMHO they suck! I want something similar to i3 where all the window decorations are completely stripped away.

Then I took this idea a step further and started thinking how absolutely mindbogglingly awesome it would be if I could configure specific virtual desktops to have this tiling WM while others would have the good old floating kwin behavior.

So I ask, does anybody know of such awesomeness? Is there anything even remotely similar to this? Even just some way to have proper tiling window management in KDE without this virtual desktop specific WM feature?

I'd also be curious to hear from people with deep understanding of the whole window management concept as to why this isn't possible if that is in fact the case. What makes it difficult to implement?

Comment: I love i3 but can't live without my trusty kde panel and other goodies either. I was trying this recently: https://github.com/faho/kwin-tiling but it has a long way to go specially in regards to multiple monitors and window resizing.

Answer (score 11):

First of all KDE is not a window manager, `kwin` is. KDE does not rely on `kwin`, so you can replace it with any other window manager, including tiling ones, that you like. One possibility of doing this is setting the [`KDEWM` environment variable](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Environment_Variables#KDEWM) to the binary of your window manager before running `startkde`.

Second, there exist tiling window managers that have the functionality of virtual desktops being designated as floating desktops. You are probably aware of that feature already.

Third, it is not possible to have a different window manager for each virtual desktop. The reason is that virtual desktops are not a concept in X11. Instead they are achieved by the window manager manually showing/hiding windows when switching desktops. There is some standardization on that, meaning there are custom, but standardized tags to identify the virtual desktop of windows. This enables other X11 clients (like a desktop switcher applet) to recognize the virtual desktop layout.
However, the X server only allows one single window manager per screen which then implements the virtual desktop behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware that KDE is not a window manager but a desktop environment and that kwin is the window manager. I also knew that I can change the window manager, I've tried that (got i3 running inside kde) but long story short, it sucks. I guess what I want is just _much_, _much_ better tiling behavior in kwin. For example being able to choose specific virtual desktops to have tiling window placement and no window decorations.

Comment: This thread was mentioned in an old post on SU that just got bumped, so your answer is old, but I'm seeing it for the 1st time.  I'm surprised by your statement that KDE does not rely on kwin.  It had been my understanding that kwin was responsible for a lot of the KDE screen features and was tightly integrated.  Can you suggest some reading where I can educate myself more on this?  Thanks.

Comment: KDE follows the NetWM protocols, so most of the desktop functionality that works with `kwin` will also work with other NetWM-adhering window managers. There is few exceptions, one thing that comes into my mind is Activities. They are not part of NetWM, so if you are using this feature, you need to stick to `kwin`. There is a nice tutorial for using other window managers, with references to other resources: https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Using_Other_Window_Managers_with_Plasma

Answer (score 2):

You could install  Compiz and   set the configuration to have no window decorations and   turn on the compiz grid  option too ! Hope this helps